# print all files and subdirectories in a give path

Tags: c, windows, recursion

So, im writing a program to recursively print the directories/sub-directories and files in a given path. im able to go in the first sub-directory and print all the files in it. my problem right now is i need find a way to step back one directory level and continue from where i left off reading. Until the condition occurs at the original directory level.

```
#include "Everything.h"
#include "Strsafe.h"

WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
HANDLE          hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
LARGE_INTEGER   fileSize;
DWORD           dwError;

void showdir(TCHAR *szDir);

int _tmain(int argc, LPCTSTR argv[])
{


    TCHAR           szDir[MAX_PATH];
    size_t          lengthOfArg;

    // verify number of parameters
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        ReportError(_T("Error: Incorrect number of arguments"), 1, FALSE);
    }

    // get the length of the entered directory
    StringCchLength(argv[1], MAX_PATH, &lengthOfArg);

    // verify that the directory path is not too long
    if (lengthOfArg > MAX_PATH - 2)
    {
        ReportError(_T("Error: Directory too long"), 2, FALSE);
    }

    // attach an asterisk (wildcard search char) to end of directory path
    StringCchCopy(szDir, MAX_PATH, argv[1]);
    StringCchCat(szDir, MAX_PATH, _T("*"));

    showdir(szDir);
}

void showdir(TCHAR *szDir)
{
    // begin the search; find the first file in the directory
    hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        ReportError(_T("Error in searching"), 3, TRUE);
    }

    //hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);
    while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0)
    {
        if ((ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0)
        {
            fileSize.LowPart = ffd.nFileSizeLow;
            fileSize.HighPart = ffd.nFileSizeHigh;
            _tprintf(_T("%s   %ld\n"), ffd.cFileName, fileSize.QuadPart);

        }       

        // did we find a directory?
        // ffd.dwFileAttributes says this is a directory (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)

        if ((ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) 
            && (_tcscmp(ffd.cFileName, _T(".")) != 0 && (_tcscmp(ffd.cFileName, _T("..")) != 0)))
        {
            TCHAR fullpath[MAX_PATH];

            StringCchCopy(fullpath, strlen(szDir) - 0, szDir);
            StringCchCat(fullpath, MAX_PATH, ffd.cFileName);
            StringCchCat(fullpath, MAX_PATH, "\\");
            _tprintf(_T("<DIR>  %s \n"), fullpath);
            StringCchCat(fullpath, MAX_PATH, _T("*"));



            showdir(fullpath);

        }   
        // continue the search; try to find more files
    } 

    // figure out if we encountered an error other than "no more files"
    dwError = GetLastError();

    if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
    {
        ReportError(_T("Error in searching"), 4, TRUE);
    }

    FindClose(hFind);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your global variables

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
HANDLE          hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
LARGE_INTEGER   fileSize;
DWORD           dwError;
```

should all be *local variables* of `showdir()`.
Then each recursion level has its own search handle, and when a nested `showdir()`
returns, the calling `showdir()` can simply continue enumerating its directory.

Note also that your code ignores the first file in each directory (the result
of `FindFirstFile()`). You could it rewrite as (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);
do {

    // ... handle ffd ...

} while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd))
```

Comment: Read the whole directory details into an array or linked list before recursing. You can then more easily carry on from where you left off.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Sure, that is also a possible solution. In any case, the state information (`WIN32_FIND_DATA` or array + current index) must be local to the function.